# Grails MongoDB index Embedded String list

Tags: grails, mongodb, indexing, grails-orm

I'm new to MongoDb and I have following question:

```
class Venue {   

String name 
List<String> tags

    static mapWith = "mongo"

static mapping = {
    tags index:true     
}


new Venue(name: 'Test1', tags:['abc', 'def']).save()
new Venue(name: 'Test2', tags:['abc', 'ghi']).save()
```

Now I wanna query for Venues with a particular tag.

```
def venues = Venue.getByTag(['def']);
```

Unfortunately the query does not work. Is there a better approach?

Now I know how to get the venues with a particular tag:
    def venues = Venue.withCriteria {
        eq 'tags', 'def'
    }

How can I discover if the index will be used?

Comment: What happens if you query using getByTags (plural)? Did you confirm that the data is actually in Mongo by querying it from the shell?

Comment: I get following exception: 

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.foo.Venue.getByTag() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[def]]
Possible solutions: getTags(), setTags(java.util.List)
Message: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.foo.Venue.getByTag() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[def]]
Possible solutions: getTags(), setTags(java.util.List)

I think it would be a great advantage using MongoDB if I can index the tags and don't have to make a Domain Obj. Collection for the tags.

Comment: I don't really know GORM, but I am guessing you read this documentation? http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html MongoDB definitely supports what you are trying to do, and I assume GORM does too, it is just a matter of finding the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamic finders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#finders) start with "find", not "get".

So you whould write something like :

```
def venues = Venue.findAllByTag("def");
```